# 'or' condition in grep -E

Tags: grep

```
1)ovs-ofctl show br-int | grep "qvo\|tap" | awk '{print $1}' | grep -E "5.tap"
```

The above(1) works fine, but if I include 'or' with `grep -E` like below command, I'm not getting any output.

```
2) ovs-ofctl show br-int | grep "qvo\|tap" | awk '{print $1}' | grep -E "5.qvo\|5.tap"


root@veer:/opt# ovs-ofctl show br-int 
OFPT_FEATURES_REPLY (xid=0x2): dpid:0000963b9c611e40
n_tables:254, n_buffers:256
capabilities: FLOW_STATS TABLE_STATS PORT_STATS QUEUE_STATS ARP_MATCH_IP
actions: OUTPUT SET_VLAN_VID SET_VLAN_PCP STRIP_VLAN SET_DL_SRC SET_DL_DST SET_NW_SRC SET_NW_DST SET_NW_TOS SET_TP_SRC SET_TP_DST ENQUEUE
 5(tap37ec1c83-29): addr:fa:f3:58:76:39:8f
     config:     0
     state:      LINK_DOWN
     current:    10GB-FD COPPER
     speed: 10000 Mbps now, 0 Mbps max
```

Any ideas, how to do this, or can we do with `awk`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `awk` you can do the following:

```
ovs-ofctl show br-int | awk '/5.tap/ || /5.qvo/'
```

or

```
ovs-ofctl show br-int | awk '/5.(tap|qvo)/'
```

Comment: Thanks for the Replay @Lambert. Actually my command is like `ovs-ofctl show br-int | grep "qvo\|tap" | awk '{print $1}' | awk '/$ofport.(tap|qvo)/'`. I'm using a variable `$ofport` can have values 5,7, etc..But when I ran that command, it is not showing any output.